# Changing column A changes column B, but changing column B does not changes column A in Google Sheets with circular dependency

Tags: google-sheets

I have enabled the recalculation setting in spreadsheet.

My column A formula is : `=ARRAYFORMULA(B:B)`

and column B formula is : `=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A)`

which is Circular dependency.

But still the updating column B doesn't changes the column A. While changes in A is properly updating column B.

Comment: are you using google-sheets or excel? Please only use the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have `=ARRAYFORMULA(B:B)` in A1 and `ARRAYFORMULA(A:A)` in B1.

If you now put, for example, number 2 in cell A2, then the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(B:B)` is no longer functional, since it has nowhere to expand: you put some data where its output would normally go. The content of B will not propagate to A.

Meanwhile, the formula `ARRAYFORMULA(A:A)` in B1 still works and it puts number 2 in cell B2 accordingly.

If you now put number 3 in column B, there is no change in column A; as previously said, you already broke the arrayformula in that column by entering a value where its output would go.

Circular dependency does not change the fact that you can't have a cake and eat it, too: you can't have a cell be in the output of a formula and also enter some value in that cell.